# Is it possible to read a property from KISSmetrics?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, kissmetrics

We're using KISSmetrics to track our users, and I want to read a property I've set on a user.

Is this possible? It's ok that it's just the data that it stored in a cookie, but I just want to read it.

If not, is there any way to just get some of the standard properties like "returning" which could be used to see if this user is a new visitor/signup.

Comment: Of course it is possible to read a cookie (as long as that is not HTTP-only). Have you tried anything? Please provide examples of the cookie values if you need help with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, KISSmetrics does not allow you to read properties you've set via JavaScript.  Only the user's identity is available.